# Mapbox gl cannot get any icon to work with 'light-v10' other than 'rocket'

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I'm using the main mapbox-gl sdk in an angular project and whatever i'm trying, any of the icons I've found on the github 'sprites' folder for all of the possible themes, none of them work except the 'rocket-15' one which is weird. I'm always hitting a:

```
Image "star-11" could not be loaded. Please make sure you have added the image with map.addImage() or a "sprite" property in your style. You can provide missing images by listening for the "styleimagemissing" map event.
```

My config:

```
this.map.addLayer({
        id: 'uprnsites',
        source: 'uprnsites',
        type: 'symbol',
        layout: {
          'text-size': 19,
          'text-transform': 'uppercase',
          'text-offset': [0, 1.5],
          'icon-image': 'star-11',
          'icon-size': 3,
          'icon-text-fit': 'none',
          'icon-text-fit-padding': [25, 25, 25, 25],
          'text-field': '{postcode} | {addressLine1} | {UPRN}'
        },
        paint: {
          'text-color': '#000',
          'text-halo-color': '#fff',
          'text-halo-width': 2
        }
      });
```

Comment: If you're using light-v10 you should be able to use any of the included sprites https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v10/sprite.json?access_token=

Comment: @AndrewHarvey cannot access that link sadly :( even after pasting my access key that I use in production in the link, are they available anywhere public?

Comment: It should work once you add your access_token. Alternatively you can just add the style to your Mapbox account as a new style and then open up Images within Mapbox Studio to see which exact icons are pre-built into the style.

Comment: it 'should' but it doesn't.